# Ubuntu18.04: Black screen on shutdown/reboot

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, amd-graphics, reboot, amd-ryzen

My Thinkpad E495 with Ubuntu18.04 halts/freezes in black screen on shutdown/reboot. Nevertheless, it boots fine even though I need to hard shutdown via power button. Disabled `quiet splash` in grub but on shutdown it does not show any logs.
I tried to reboot with `sudo reboot -d` or `sudo reboot -f` but it still ends in a black screen.

System spec:
AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with integrated AMD Radeon vega grahpics

```
...@ThinkPad-E495:~$ uname --kernel-release
5.3.0-53-generic
...@ThinkPad-E495:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path            Device   Class          Description
=======================================================
                             system         20NECTO1WW (LENOVO_MT_20NE_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad E495)
/0                           bus            20NECTO1WW
/0/1                         memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/1/0                       memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/1/1                       memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/3                         memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/4                         memory         2MiB L2 cache
/0/5                         memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/6                         processor      AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
/0/e                         memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/100                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/0.2                   generic        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.1                   bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.1/0                 storage        NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
/0/100/1.2                   bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.2/0        enp2s0   network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1.3                   bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.3/0                 generic        RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1.6                   bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/1.6/0        wlp4s0   network        RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
/0/100/8.1                   bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.1/0                 display        Picasso
/0/100/8.1/0.1               multimedia     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
/0/100/8.1/0.2               generic        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.1/0.3               bus            Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0    usb1     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1    usb2     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4               bus            Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.1/0.4/0    usb3     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4/0/1           communication  Bluetooth Radio
/0/100/8.1/0.4/0/2           multimedia     Integrated Camera
/0/100/8.1/0.4/1    usb4     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.5               multimedia     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/8.1/0.6               multimedia     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/100/14                    bus            FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                  bridge         FCH LPC Bridge
/0/101                       bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/102                       bridge         Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/103                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/104                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/105                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/106                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/107                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/108                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/109                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/0/10a                       bridge         Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
/1                           power          01AV446
/2                  docker0  network        Ethernet interface
```

I am happy to provide you with any logs, just point me in the right direction. Right now, I do not know which logs or what keywords to look for.

Comment: This is a bug on AMD Ryzen CPUs on kernel versions 5.3.0-52 and later. This bug has been reported Bug [#1880041](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe/+bug/1880041)

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug on AMD Ryzen CPUs on kernel versions 5.3.0-52 and later. This bug has been reported [#1880041](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe/+bug/1880041).