# Lenovo Ideapad s340 running Ubuntu 18.04 does not reboot/shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, lenovo

My laptop, Lenovo Ideapad s340, will not shut down or reboot. I have to press the power button to switch it off. I have tried several suggestions including acpi but I still have this problem.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on AMD Ryzen CPUs on kernel versions!
This bug has been solved:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1244512

Comment: That's right. The Lenovo IdeaPad S340 does have a Ryzen CPU.